# Bootstrap: Accordion Collapse stopped working with Bootstrap 2.0.3

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, accordion

My accordion using `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-parent="#selector"`works fine with Bootstrap 2.0.2, but when I switch to 2.0.3 the accordion functionality stops working.

It still opens and closes the **target** `div`, but it won't automatically close an open **target** `div` when another `td` with `data-toggle="collapse"` is clicked.

You can see it not working with 2.0.3 here: http://chooserealtoday.com/#faq

The following code example is also on JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/N7MN9/3/.

```
<table id="faq-table" class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td class="question" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#answer1" data-parent="#faq-table">
      <p><strong>What is your name?</strong></p>
      <div id="answer1" class="answer collapse">
        <p>Mark Rummel</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="question" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#answer2" data-parent="#faq-table">
       <p><strong>What is your favorite color?</strong></p>
       <div id="answer2" class="answer collapse">
         <p>Blue, no yellow.</p>
       </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks for any help you can offer on this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two options

- use divs instead of table (go for the example http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse )
- modify bootstrap.js and replace :

`actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.find('> .accordion-group > .in')`

by the 2.0.2 version :

`actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.find('.in')`

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. I modified bootstrap.min.js, so instead of `actives = ...`, I replaced  `d = ...`.

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar but related problem; your fix (option 2) worked a treat. I wonder why they made that change? It totally doesn't gel with the documentation for collapse.js

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this without modifying the Bootstrap files: just throw in the .accordion-group class.

[Reference](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2784)

Comment: because the inheritance is strictly checked as of 2.0.3 (the selector used is `> .accordion-group > .in`) this won't work if you are trying to use a table to build a collapse group (or any structure that doesn't match that selector). I built [an extension](https://github.com/lastobelus/bootstrap-collapse-activeselector) that lets you specify the selector used to find active siblings.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [this extension](https://github.com/lastobelus/bootstrap-collapse-activeselector) to allow using collapse with a table. It allows you to specify the selector used to find active siblings in a collapse group.

[bootstrap-collapse-activeselector](https://github.com/lastobelus/bootstrap-collapse-activeselector)